# ref list isn't modified outside command class

Tags: c#, .net

I would like one class to modify the list fields of another class. I pass both list fields as references. The problem is, one list is modified in the end, and second is not. I don't understand why. I wanted to check my idea with a minimal working example, where everything works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _20190424_ref_list_del
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListManager testObj = new ListManager();
            testObj.startJob();
        }
    }

    class ListManager
    {
        private List<int> ListToExpand;
        private List<int> ListToShorten;

        public ListManager()
        {
            ListToExpand = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            ListToShorten = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        }

        public void startJob()
        {
            EditList editObj = new EditList(ref ListToExpand, ref ListToShorten);
            editObj.doJob();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("List to expand:");
            foreach (int x in ListToExpand)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(x.ToString());
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("List to shorten:");
            foreach (int x in ListToShorten)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(x.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

    class EditList
    {
        private List<int> ListToExpand;
        private List<int> ListToShorten;

        public EditList(ref List<int> listToExpand, ref List<int> listToShorten)
        {
            ListToExpand = listToExpand;
            ListToShorten = listToShorten;
        }

        public void doJob()
        {
            ListToExpand.Add(4);
            ListToShorten.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is:

1. Init two lists
2. Expand first and shorten another.
3. Check if there is an effect outside the working class, which modifies lists.

For this reason, I'm using `ref`. But the same approach in my real app fails. I have two lists too. One to be expanded, second to be shortened.

Let me explain what part of my code does: There is a list of samples from a Modbus device. Some of the samples require to be joined into bigger ones (because some of the values are so large that have values of int32 which need to be stored in two int16 registers).

I have a class with the Command design pattern which works as follows:

- Create a Command object which takes:

  1. (ref) input list of single samples
  2. list of samples to be joined
  3. (ref) list of samples joined to double ones
- Build double samples
- Remove single samples which have been joined

While testing, the list of double samples are filled, but the list of single ones isn't shortened. I don't understand why, because it looks like I'm using the same approach as in the minimal working example. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Test Case:

```
namespace put_samples_into_dbTests.Unit.Commands
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GetDoubleSamples
    {
        List<Sample> SingleSamples;
        List<PatternSample32> SamplesPattern;
        List<Sample32> ResultSamples;
        int MaxSources = 2;
        int MaxObjects = 3;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInit()
        {
            SingleSamples = new List<Sample>();
            SamplesPattern = new List<PatternSample32>();
            ResultSamples = new List<Sample32>();

            for (byte i = 1; i <= MaxSources; i++)
            {
                for (byte k = 2; k <= MaxObjects; k++)
                {
                    SamplesPattern.Add(new PatternSample32(i, k, 1, 2));
                }
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void BuildFrom1Set()
        {
            int howManySamples32 = MaxSources * (MaxObjects-1);
            int howManySamples = MaxSources* ((1 + MaxObjects) * MaxObjects / 2) - howManySamples32 *2;
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;


            for (byte i = 1; i <= MaxSources; i++)
            {
                for (byte k = 1; k <= MaxObjects; k++)
                {
                    for (byte l = 1; l <= k; l++)
                    {
                        SingleSamples.Add(new Sample(dateTime, i, k, l, 1, true));
                    }
                }
            }

            Command command = new GetDoubleSamples(ref SingleSamples, SamplesPattern , ref ResultSamples );
            command.Execute();

            Assert.AreEqual(howManySamples, SingleSamples.Count); // [!]
            Assert.AreEqual(howManySamples32, ResultSamples.Count);

        }
```

Now, do take a look at my GetDoubleSamples command:

```
public class GetDoubleSamples : Command
    {
        private List<Sample> SingleSamples;
        private List<PatternSample32> DoubleSamplesPattern;
        private List<Sample32> ResultSamples;
        private List<Sample> ProcessedSamples;

        public GetDoubleSamples (ref List<Sample> singleSamples, List<PatternSamples32> doubleSamplesPattern, ref List<Sample32> resultSamples)
        {
            SingleSamples = singleSamples;
            doubleSamplesPattern = doubleSamplesPattern;
            ResultSamples = resultSamples;
            ProcessedSamples = new List<Sample>();
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            SortSamples();
            foreach (List<Sample> samplesSet in GenerateSets())
            {
                ResultSamples.AddRange(BuildDoubles(samplesSet ));
            }
            DeleteProcessedSamples();
        }
         private void DeleteProcessedSamples()
        {
            SingleSamples = SingleSamples.Except(ProcessedSamples).ToList();
        }
}
```

And the problem is, when I check for the amount of created double samples - it's okay. But the same (I suppose) kind of list of simple samples isn't reduced of processed samples. When I debug the code, I see that inside the class the mentioned list is modified. But once I get outside Execute methods and get outside Command class, I lose that modified list and get back to the original one. Just as if my list wasn't passed as a reference.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?
Any suggestions, also about rearranging my test method, will be appreciated! :-)

Comment: Drive-by comment: "For this reason, I'm using ref" - `List<T>` is a reference type already. You're not actually using the fact that the parameter is a `ref` parameter. (It *does* make a difference even with reference types, but you're not using that difference.)

Comment: But when I remove `ref`, it gives no effect

Comment: The ref you've got in your current code has *no impact whatsoever*. All you're doing is copying a reference (as a value) into the fields in the constructor. You need to understand the difference between "changing the value of a field to refer to a different object" and "modifying the data within an object". See if https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html helps.

Comment: I removed `ref`s from both definition of GetDoubleSamples constructor and implemantation of GetDoubleSamples tests, but still without effects

Comment: Yes, it won't change anything in this case - but it's important that you understand *why* it won't do anything. Fundamentally, your `DeleteProcessedSamples` method should probably be removing elements from the *existing* list rather than assigning a new list to the field, as the latter doesn't have any impact on any existing lists. (Although I'd argue that mutating a list that was passed into a constructor isn't terribly pleasant either...)